# ORM update does not support file upload

Tags: django, image, orm, save

I have following model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_active=models.BooleanField()
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='category')
    def __unicode__(self):
       name = str(self.name)
       return name
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('category','Category'),
            ('view_category', 'View category'),
        )
```

My form class is as follows

```
class categoryForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'box'}),max_length=32,label='Category',required=True)
    is_active = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput,required=False)
    photo = forms.FileField(
            required=False,
            label='Select an Image',
            help_text='max. 4 megabytes'
            )
```

In view.py I have the following

```
formdata = categoryForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if formdata.is_valid():
            cd = formdata.cleaned_data
            p1=Category()
            p1.id=cd['id']
            p1.name=cd['name']
            p1.is_active=cd['is_active']
            p1.photo=cd['photo']
            p1.save()
```

It is working fine but when i changed it to the following, image is not uploaded

```
Category.objects.filter(id='%s'%(cd['id'])).update(name='%s'%(cd['name']),
                                    is_active='%s'%(cd['is_active']),
                                   photo=cd['photo']
                                   )
```

I think the second method is faster way, but why it is not working for ImageField

Answer (score 0):

the id in the code pasted above is a string, try converting it to an int. That will i guess make the filter query work and hence make the update on it work as well.

Comment: filter query is working fine.Other fields (except image) are being updated

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be passing a string to `is_active`. Just pass the boolean and it should work. Also, you shouldn't be writing code like `'%s' % string`; you can just use `string`

Comment: True, but still the problem is there ... no image upload using second method .. please help me

Comment: From your code sample 1, it looks like you are creating a new Category object. Why are you then using `filter` in your second code sample? You should be using `Category.objects.create(id=..., is_active=...)`. See the django docs for an example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create

Comment: Filter + update will make the execution faster , create objects in update query will 1st find out whether that id exists or not, if yes it will update else it will insert .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)